# Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro (dual boot with Windows 8.1).
Everything seems to work fine except wifi. I tried to follow some of the suggestions on the forum for similar issues with Yoga 2 but had no luck.
Has anyone successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 on Yoga 3 Pro and managed to get the internet working. Any tips would be helpful.
Thanks,
Santo

Comment: Have you seen [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)?

Answer (score 4):

I have the same ultrabook and I managed to fix mine with the above suggestion. I first ran:

```
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

Then I created a blacklist with:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/myownblacklist.conf
```

Added the following line:

```
blacklist ideapad_laptop
```

Rebooted and Wifi working fine from then on. I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 Gnome 3 Edition and works pretty well. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I have my yoga 3 on WiFi with ubuntu 14.10.   Make sure you check the option to install third party drivers during installation.  You also need to make sure that the ideapad_laptop kernel module is not loaded, add a line "blacklist ideapad_laptop" to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and reboot.

Comment: I am having no such luck. I tried updated my ideapad-laptop.c with the suggestions on the internet and replacing it but its still hard blocked.

Comment: It was the option to install third party drivers that fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I started a HOWTO for installing Linux on the Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro

https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md

While the information. The ideapad_laptop module has been fixed and does no longer disable Wifi and Bluetooth on the Yoga 3. Meaning it is completely sufficient to install the Broadcom drivers with the latest Ubuntu 14.10 Kernel.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this on my Yoga 3 with Ubuntu 14.10 with latest apt-get upgrade all, and the broadcom wifi works after removing the ideapad_laptop module (I put modprobe -r /etc/rc.local). And of course you might need to do: rfkill unblock all

I wrote a short summary at of installation process at:

http://goo.gl/NvwMzb

Nice machine though the battery time is a tradeoff for the weight.

Cheers
FK