# can't install Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro

Tags: lenovo

I have a new Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro but I can't install Ubuntu 14.04 on it.

I tried working through the [instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/367963/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-2-pro/485632#485632) for the Yoga 2, but after editing the grub boot line and pressing enter, the screen goes blank and stays blank. But the power is on. I wonder if perhaps the system is waiting for me to do something but I can't see it because the screen is blank. I did add the acpi_backlight=vendor bit to the boot line (before quiet) so that is probably not the issue....

I have to hold down the power button for ~20 seconds to get the power to turn off and then I can turn it back on and repeat the process, but I never get past that point. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you try placing the boot parameter after splash such that the grub boot line reads, GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor" Also be sure to save your changes and run "sudo update-grub" (without quotes) after, if you haven't been doing so already. I also note that the instructions link you provided explains how to install Ubuntu on an older Yoga. How does live media behave when you don't edit the grub boot line?

Comment: longsleep's guide gives up on this model because the fan runs continuously. According to this [Lenovo community posting](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Edge-Yoga-Flex-Laptops/Yoga-13-Fan-Noise/ta-p/1065093), this can be fixed by flashing the embedded controller with an alternate thermal table.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Ubuntu 14.10 instead of 14.04. See my [guide](https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md).

Answer (score 0):

No need to edit Grub.  Insert USB boot drive.  Push button on right side for boot menu.  Change to legacy in BIOS.  Change to boot USB drive and install.  Wireless will not work.  Go here for solution: [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549392/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-3-pro) Touchpad and Touch screen will not work.  Upgrade to kernel 3.18 to fix this but wireless will again not work and their is no solution presently.

Comment: This information is outdated. Wifi works fine starting with Ubuntu 14.10 or 15.04. I have written a complete [guide](https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md).