# Very slow wifi on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro

Tags: wireless, 14.10, lenovo, broadcom, ubuntu-gnome

I got very slow wifi connection on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro.
I am using Ubuntu 14.10 Gnome.

Because wifi is not working out of the box currently I set it up with

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
```

as adviced in https://askubuntu.com/a/585545/381505

Normal speed from wifi network I am connected to is 70-90 Mbps.
I got it on windows 8.1 as well as on other devices.

Unfortunately on ubuntu in 4/5 cases I got connection at speed 2-3 Mbps (tested with http://speedtest.net).

I tried

```
 sudo iw dev wlan0 set power_save off
```

without success.

I checked of course (with system monitor) that there is no other transfer in background.

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 15 would give you better driver options for this device.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like problem was made by

```
Autosuspend for USB device BCM20702A0 [Broadcom Corp]
```

listed in `Tunables` tab in `powertop`. Disabling that fixed the problem.

Comment: This has massively improved my quality of life.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` shows an Intel wireless device, it can be sped up considerably with `echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

Comment: `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net` shows 
`01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0623]
 Kernel driver in use: wl`

Should I still try above?

Comment: I tried it and I didn't see any improvement.