# Running testdisk off a 14.04 Live USB without internet access

Tags: live-usb, data-recovery, lenovo

Short of it is that I've fried my MFT something wicked and am trying to get data off the Windows partition. My laptop is a Lenovo Yoga 3 14, which has [documented issues with the Ubuntu Broadcom drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549392/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-3-pro), and I'm not able to start the wifi from the Live USB even if I follow the instructions in that link. So, no internet. I don't want to install Ubuntu on the hard drive in case it damages the Windows partition further. I have downloaded the newest version of [testdisk for Linux](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download), popped it on another USB drive, and am now trying to run testdisk, but with no luck:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/testdisk-7.0$ sudo ./testdisk_static
sudo: ./testdisk_static: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/testdisk-7.0$ sudo testdisk_static
sudo: testdisk_static: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/Desktop/testdisk-7.0$ sudo -i
root@ubuntu:~# cd /home/ubuntu/Desktop/testdisk-7.0/ && ./testdisk_static
-bash: ./testdisk_static: Permission denied
```

What's going on, and am I able to run testdisk without access to `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
chmod +x testdisk_static
```

Then:

```
./testdisk_static
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu :-) Please add more details into your answer, and if possible, test in an own computer, that it works (can solve the problem in the question).