# yoga 3 pro touchpad and touch screen

Tags: drivers, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I have new laptop yoga 900. I have install ubuntu 15.10 on it. The problem is that touchpad and touch screen are not detected (I solved wifi problem with this : [Intel wireless 8260 - unclaimed network](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693109/intel-wireless-8260-unclaimed-network), [Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549392/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-3-pro)), but touchpad and touchscreen style not working. Can someone help me to solve this ?
ps :

```
xprint --list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Lenovo EasyCamera                         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: what are all this things "↳"? Whatever they are, they make reading your question extremely difficult.

Comment: this is the output of command xprint --list, i have changed nothing

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry about that, my bad :).

Comment: it seems that the new kernel version has solved the problem. I have not try i by myself. I have recompiled my kernel and since then it works good. I am using Kubuntu. sometime after suspend i must use Ctrl-F1 Ctrl-F7 to re-enable touch-pad. bet apart from that everything is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved now because the new kernel version support **Yoga 900**. I am using `4.6.0-0` and it is working fine. No need to recompile the kernel :)