# Lenovo Yoga3 Pro wifi driver does not work

Tags: wireless, 16.04, lenovo, broadcom, yoga-2

I checked 
[Ubuntu on Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro](https://askubuntu.com/questions/549392/ubuntu-on-lenovo-yoga-3-pro)

https://github.com/longsleep/yoga3pro-linux/blob/master/Yoga%203%20Linux%20HOWTO.md

and

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) (most exhaustive list still no clue)

01:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 03)

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

```
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 03
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:18 memory:c1200000-c1207fff memory:c1000000-c11fffff

garshah@jigarshah-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ 
jigarshah@jigarshah-Lenovo-YOGA-3-Pro-1370:~$ dmesg | grep -i firmware
[    2.757845] hid-rmi 0018:06CB:2714.0001: firmware id: 0
[    4.251276] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0489-e07a.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.196389] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[    5.198360] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
[   58.628045] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[   58.628072] ieee80211 phy2: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29


wireless card info
```

14e4:43b1 rev 03

Nothing really helped.

I need it to work offline as no wifi and no other AP device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Turn off the secure boot
2. Remove `bcmwl-kernel-source`:

   ```
   sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```
3. Re-install `bcmwl-kernel-source`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
   ```
4. Reboot. Your wireless should now be working.

Check [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770490/broadcom-wireless-drivers-unclaimed-after-installing-update-16-04) for more information.

Comment: I am so grateful, this worked flawlessly! I needed just to use my android phone and tether the internet connection via the USB port.