# Wifi not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have problems with wifi on Ubuntu 16:04 64bit. The problems started after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04.
I've tried reinstall wifi drivers, but there was an error:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1.515 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 286139 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) over (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.248+bdcom-0ubuntu8) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.248+bdcom DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-22-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.4.0-22-generic
Done.
```

`wl`:

```
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-22-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod..........

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic
```

`ifconfig`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:76:1c:cd:b7:bd  
          inet addr:192.168.1.193  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f276:1cff:fecd:b7bd/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:491801 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:169157 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:233366815 (233.3 MB)  TX bytes:22879754 (22.8 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:41422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:41422 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:3278423 (3.2 MB)  TX bytes:3278423 (3.2 MB)
```

`lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Complex
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri [Radeon R6 Graphics]
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kaveri HDMI/DP Audio Controller
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1425
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:03.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Root Port
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1424
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 40)
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 30h-3fh) Processor Function 5
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265]
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
02:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
```

`lsb_release -a`:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

`uname -a`:

```
Linux febriyanti-notebookif 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Why why there is an error "DKMS: install completed. modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Required key not available update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated) Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8) ... update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-22-generic"?
```

What should I do so that my wifi can work again?

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/780069/ubuntu-16-04-only-connecting-to-ethernet-no-wifi-option/780095#780095

Comment: @chili555 thanks for your respon, it works for me. My problem solved.