# Wireless not working on HP EliteBook 745G2

Tags: networking, lubuntu

After installing lubuntu alongside windows on my laptop, I noticed my wireless internet wasn't working (wired internet does). After a couple of hours on google and trying numerous other methods, I still haven't managed to fix it.

I'm honestly a bit of a newbie at linux, but I figured this would be useful information:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 24 Jun 2016 09:24 EDT -0400

Booted last: 24 Jun 2016 00:00 EDT -0400

Script from: 30 Apr 2015 17:23 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Lubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0e)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:221c]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:05e2]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04ca:704d Lite-On Technology Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21f1 Broadcom Corp. HP Portable Bumble Bee
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

'pccardctl' is not installed (package "pcmciautils").

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

wl                   6365184  0
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
cfg80211              565248  1 wl
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp1s0f0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'enp1s0f0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:192.168.2.19  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::83c2:3d5c:ecc8:d35a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3372 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2760 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1117665 (1.1 MB)  TX bytes:397219 (397.2 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlo1' [IF]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:100
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:39 

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp1s0f0  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.254   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp1s0f0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enp1s0f0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search home

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0f0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 2.3LK-NAPI
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0f0' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:01:00.0/net/enp1s0f0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp1s0f0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6fe9b616-6dfe-4f24-be27-47386c73e515
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6fe9b616-6dfe-4f24-be27-47386c73e515 | Wired connection 1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.2.19/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.2.254
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.2.254
IP4.DNS[2]:                             195.121.1.34
IP4.DNS[3]:                             195.121.1.66
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 192.168.2.254
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1466860594
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       routers = 192.168.2.254
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 192.168.2.19
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       domain_name = home
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.2.255
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 86400
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       domain_name_servers = 192.168.2.254 195.121.1.34 195.121.1.66
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 192.168.2.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.2.254
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::83c2:3d5c:ecc8:d35a/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlo1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         wl
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlo1' [IF]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.2/0000:02:00.0/net/wlo1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  * 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wi-Fi connection 1]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Wi-Fi connection 1 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=zapple 1st floor
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/New_York (based on set time zone)

country DE: DFS-ETSI
    (2400 - 2483 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), NO-OUTDOOR, DFS
    (5470 - 5725 @ 160), (N/A, 26), (0 ms), DFS
    (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp1s0f0  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlo1      32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 32 : 5.16 GHz
          Channel 34 : 5.17 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 38 : 5.19 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 42 : 5.21 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 46 : 5.23 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 50 : 5.25 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 54 : 5.27 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 58 : 5.29 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 62 : 5.31 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 66 : 5.33 GHz
          Channel 68 : 5.34 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp1s0f0  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlo1      No scan results

##### module infos ######################

[wl]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/updates/dkms/wl.ko
license:        MIXED/Proprietary
srcversion:     4DDC5FCDB1E30F7DFDCA530
depends:        cfg80211
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           passivemode:int
parm:           wl_txq_thresh:int
parm:           oneonly:int
parm:           piomode:int
parm:           instance_base:int
parm:           nompc:int
parm:           intf_name:string

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     00D8DA6D3B739DDD31FFF50
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-21-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf]
blacklist b43
blacklist b43legacy
blacklist ssb
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist brcm80211
blacklist brcmfmac
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/libpisock9.conf]
blacklist visor

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

grep: /etc/udev/rules.d/*net*.rules: No such file or directory

##### dmesg #############################

[   15.674697] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21f1.hcd failed with error -2
[   15.674707] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-0a5c-21f1.hcd not found
[   16.454008] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   16.460761] wl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   16.464276] wl 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   16.536735] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4359 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)
[   16.539254] wl 0000:02:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
[   20.668512] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
[   45.749819] ERROR @wl_dev_intvar_get : error (-1) (repeated 4 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

If any additional information is of use, I will be more than happy to provide it.

**EDIT:**

I Forgot to mention, but the wireless connection does work on the Windows I dualboot on.

**Possible duplicates:** 
[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)
I have already tried the steps suggested by this post. First, I installed the 'bcmwl-kernel-source' package. After rebooting no wireless connections showed up in another program I have installed, 'WiFi Radar'. Further down in the answer, it was suggested to also try 'firmware-b43-installer'. The same thing happend. The output of the wireless troubleshooting script above was generated just after this step.

[Ubuntu 16.04 - only connecting to ethernet, no wifi option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780069/ubuntu-16-04-only-connecting-to-ethernet-no-wifi-option)
I checked if secureboot was on, and it wasn't. Running 'sudo modprobe wl' gave the following error: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried what was suggested in that thread, without success.

Comment: Did you read the guide to the end? What do you mean "without success"? Could you install the driver?

Comment: What is the exact result of this terminal command? `sudo modprobe wl`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes, I was able to install the drivers. Sorry for the ambiguity in my answer. For the particular thread, I followed all the steps and installed the driver corrosponding to my card (bcmwl-kernel-source), rebooted. I used 'WiFi radar' to check if I had any connections, and I didn't.
After that, I read under the 'IMPORTANT NOTE' section of the metnioned thread, that I could try to install the firmware-b43-installer package. I didn't notice any other results than with the other driver, only that I got a slightly differant output when I ran iwconfig.

Comment: @chili555 I read the thread you linked to,  secure boot is off. After running the command in your second post, I got: modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-21-generic

Comment: I suggest: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` Does it go well? If not, post the errors; if so, then try again: `sudo modprobe wl`

Comment: I ran the command you suggested.  'Sudo modprobe wl' runs, but gives no output.  I regenerated the contents of the wireless script (perhaps it is useful, as I am running a differnt driver now I think), it can be found here: [link](http://pastebin.com/gb1VZnqz)

Comment: Not much wrong there, although it shows your country code as DE (Germany) but that, based on the time zone set, you might be in USA. Which is it? If you reboot with the ethernet detached, does it scan? `sudo iwlist scan`

Comment: @chili555 Sorry for the late reply. I got the following output: [link](http://pastebin.com/wRrxg4Pb). You are correct, I have changed the country code to NL ('iw set reg NL'  is the correct command I believe). I also set the timezone to the correct value for NL.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I don't quite understand what this link has to do with this problem. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it though.