# Having trouble disabling secure boot

Tags: boot, wireless, bios, secure-boot

I have been trying to fix a problem that was previously asked here: 
[Ubuntu 16.04 - only connecting to ethernet, no wifi option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780069/ubuntu-16-04-only-connecting-to-ethernet-no-wifi-option)
(note for those who do not wish to follow the link: I recently installed Ubuntu but I am unable to connect to wifi. The solution to this bug is to disable secure boot)

When I open the boot options upon startup I am met with the following screen:

[image]

I noticed that above "Legacy Boot" it does not say whether or not it is doing a secure boot, as I have noticed is typical when I have googled this issue. Example from the web:

[image]

When I open BIOS setup, I am given the following screen:

[image]

I have searched through all of the options on both the main and BIOS setup screens and cannot find any option to disable secure boot. Any suggestions? Also it may be relevant that Ubuntu is the only OS on this computer. Thanks for your help

Comment: It appears that, by selecting *Legacy* and not *UEFI* that you have disabled secure boot. Aren't you now able to modprobe your wireless driver without complaint?

Comment: Echoing chili555, choosing Legacy Boot means you have disabled secure boot

Comment: You can check in terminal with `mokitil --sb-state`

Answer (score 0):

I just checked on my machine, a Dell OptiPlex 7010. I have Legacy Mode enabled. And when looking in the menu there is a Secure Boot menu item that you do not have:
[image]

Maybe your firmware version doesn't support Secure Boot. See if you can find a more recent BIOS/UEFI version.

Also, here is where you disable UEFI and enable Legacy Boot:
[image]